# Async Web Service Requests from WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, asynchronous

I have tried (and failed) to make asynchronous web service calls from a WPF application.

I implemented a `BackgroundWorker` in my code which should do the work, when you press the "Send" button on my GUI. It does what it's supposed to, *some of the time*, but ultimately it doesn't actually run asynchronous.

When you press the button in my GUI the following code fires:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sQuantity = boxQuantity.Text;
    progressBar.Maximum = double.Parse(sQuantity);
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

`sQuantity` is just a box with a number in it. It will determine how many requests you sent to the web service at once.

`progressBar` is what you would expect: A progress bar.

`worker.RunWorkerAsync()` is where I call the `DoWork` method. It looks like this:

```
void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    EnableButton(false);
    List<LoanRequestNoCreditScoreDTO> dtoList = GetData();
    foreach (LoanRequestNoCreditScoreDTO dto in dtoList)
    {
        using (LoanBrokerWS.LoanBrokerWSClient client = new LoanBrokerWS.LoanBrokerWSClient())
        {
            try
            {
                Task<LoanQuoteDTO> lq = RequestQuote(dto, client);
                LoanQuoteDTO response = lq.Result;
                lq.Dispose();
                String responseMsg = response.SSN + "\n" + response.interestRate + "\n" + response.BankName + "\n------\n";
                AppendText(responseMsg);
                worker_ProgressChanged();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppendText(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException.Message + "\n");
                worker_ProgressChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    EnableButton(true);
}
```

Ultimately, this is where I screw up of course. I want the application to send as many requests as the user specified. So if I wrote 10 in quantity, I would send 10 requests. The `RequestQuote()` method calls the following code:

```
private async Task<LoanQuoteDTO> RequestQuote(LoanRequestNoCreditScoreDTO dto, LoanBrokerWS.LoanBrokerWSClient client)
{
    LoanQuoteDTO response = await client.GetLoanQuoteAsync(dto.SSN, dto.LoanAmount, dto.LoanDuration);
    return response;
}
```

How would I make the `DoWork` method actually send requests asynchronous?

Comment: It is running asynchronously; what you're looking for is *concurrent* execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code as-is is asynchronous with respect to the UI thread; what you're asking about it *concurrency*. Any kind of complex I/O work is best done with `async`/`await`, so I'm going to throw out your background worker and just use straight `async`.

First, the button handler will handle its own enabling/disabling and executing the main download:

```
private async void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var quantity = int.Parse(boxQuantity.Text);
  btnSend.Enabled = false;
  await DownloadAsync(quantity);
  btnSend.Enabled = true;
}
```

The main download will create a rate-limiting `SemaphoreSlim` (a common type used to throttle concurrent asynchronous operations), and wait for all the individual downloads to complete:

```
private async Task DownloadAsync(int quantity)
{
  var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(quantity);
  var tasks = GetData().Select(dto => DownloadAsync(dto, semaphore));
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

The individual downloads will each first rate-limit themselves, and then do the actual download:

```
private async Task DownloadAsync(LoanRequestNoCreditScoreDTO dto, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
  await semaphore.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    using (LoanBrokerWS.LoanBrokerWSClient client = new LoanBrokerWS.LoanBrokerWSClient())
    {
      var response = await RequestQuoteAsync(dto, client);
    }        
  }
  finally
  {
    semaphore.Release();
  }
}
```

For doing progress reports, I'd recommend using the types intended for that pattern (`IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>`). First, you decide what data you want in your progress report; in this case, it could just be a string. Then, you create your progress handler:

```
private async void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var quantity = int.Parse(boxQuantity.Text);
  var progress = new Progress<string>(update =>
  {
    AppendText(update);
    progressBar.Value = progressBar.Value + 1;
  });
  progressBar.Maximum = ...; // not "quantity"
  btnSend.Enabled = false;
  await DownloadAsync(quantity, progress);
  btnSend.Enabled = true;
}
```

(Note that `progressBar.Maximum = double.Parse(sQuantity);` in the original code was wrong; you should set it to the *total* number of downloads).

Then the `IProgress<string>` just gets passed down:

```
private async Task DownloadAsync(int quantity, IProgress<string> progress)
{
  var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(quantity);
  var tasks = GetData().Select(dto => DownloadAsync(dto, semaphore, progress));
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

And when you have progress to report, you use that instance:

```
private async Task DownloadAsync(LoanRequestNoCreditScoreDTO dto, SemaphoreSlim semaphore, IProgress<string> progress)
{
  await semaphore.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    using (LoanBrokerWS.LoanBrokerWSClient client = new LoanBrokerWS.LoanBrokerWSClient())
    {
      var response = await RequestQuoteAsync(dto, client);
      progress.Report(response.SSN + "\n" + response.interestRate + "\n" + response.BankName + "\n------\n");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    progress.Report(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.InnerException.Message + "\n");
  }
  finally
  {
    semaphore.Release();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this through answer (and lesson) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you call RequestQuote with await keyword then in every call it waits for the response and you can't make another. so simply use your proxy's "**completed event handler**" for your async method and call RequestQuote method back to back and give your responses in the event handler.